# Supress password prompt in GPG

Tags: pgp

Using GnuPG one can symmetrically encrypt a file using:

```
gpg -c --cipher-algo TWOFISH --digest-algo SHA512 secret.txt
```

and decrypt using:

```
gpg -d -o secret.txt secret.txt.gpg
```

After running these commands a window pops up and asks for the password. I would like to run these commands out of a program using golangs 'exec' or pythons 'os.system'. How do I suppress this window and pass the password via command line? I couldn't find something like a --password option in the man pages.

Comment: As far as I know, the window is created by the pinetry program. If you uninstall it you'll have a dialog directly in the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You have some choices:

```
echo "aqw" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 -d -o output.txt secret.txt.gpg
```

or

```
gpg --batch --passphrase "aqw" -d -o output.txt secret.txt.gpg
```

or

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-file passphrase.txt -d -o output.txt secret.txt.gpg
```

(if you don't want to write your passphrase into the commandline)

Comment: None of these seem to work with mit GPG installation.

Comment: it works on mine: Debian unstable.

Comment: I use Mint and gpg 1.4.16 could you post your GPG version?

Comment: On my debian unstable I've: gnupg 1.4.18-6